# When using a DependencyProperty, how can I tell the the difference between an inherited value and an assigned one

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

The `DependencyProperty` system is really useful in a number of ways, but one which is causing me a little trouble at the moment is, with the DataContext property, doing some type checking. See below for my current approach, which already stops invalid types from causing weird magic-sting-namespace-collisions, but won't actually error on a value being assigned.

Only problem is I can't work out how to tell the difference between the two ways a value can end up in a property. Can someone tell me how to do this?

**Current approach:**

(Please forgive errors, this is typed from memory, so might have a couple of elements wrong, but it gives the idea.)

*Base Class*

```
public class MyControlBase : FrameworkElement
{

    static MyControlBase() 
    {
        DataContextProperty.OverrideDefaultMetadata(
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                DataContextProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(MyControlBase)).DefaultValue,
                (s,e) => {},
                (s,e) =>
                {
                    var sender = s as MyControlBase;
                    if (sender == null || e == null || sender.ExpectedType == null) 
                        return e;
                    var oOut = sender.ExpectedType == typeof(e) ? e : null;
                    // WANTED:
                    if (!IsInheritedDPValue(sender, DataContextProperty) && e != null && oOut == null)
                        throw ArgumentException("Assigned value not of expected type");
                    return Out;
                }
            )
        );
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpectedTypeProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ExpectedType", 
            typeof(Type),
            typeof(MyControlBase)
            new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );
    public Type ExpectedType {
        get {return GetValue(ExpectedTypeProperty) as Type;}
        set {SetValue(ExpectedTypeProperty, value);}
    }

}
```

*Child classes*

```
public class MyControlT1 {
    static MyControlT1()
    {
        ExpectedTypeProperty.OverrideDefaultMetadata(
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                typeof(MyControlT1ViewModel)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it matter?  If you want to make sure that your DataContext is of the anticipated type, you should throw an exception whenever it's not correct - regardless of whether it was inherited or not.  You could always try just a ReferenceEquals between the current value and the parent's value if you really need to know.

Comment: It might do. For instance, can I be sure the value will get coerced to null in the case of an exception (of course, I can try and see, and will check). That's the core behavior I'm after - the exception would more be to explicitly force consumers of the object to be careful what they assign to it, whereas since there's nothing I can do about the inherited value, it seems like it'll cause more problems than it'll prevent to throw every time the inherited value changes (though, of course, it would be pretty easy to make that an option too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how the value got assigned to the dependency property, you can use

```
DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
```

This method returns a `ValueSource` object, which has a `BaseValueSource` property. It is an enum that has a value according to the place the value came from (inherited, local value, trigger and so on).

If the value was inherited from a parent object, the value of `BaseValueSource` would be `Inherited`. If the value was directly assigned to the element, the value would be `Local`.

You can look up all possible values of `BaseValueSource` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.basevaluesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx